# iPhone SDK: Adding Images To a UITextView In The Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

You know how when you add text to a UITextView and it displays only text? Well, I also want to add images along with the text so that when I scroll, it displays the text with the images fitted along with the text.

How can I do that in **BOTH** the *Xcode* and the *Interface Builder*??

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Instead, you should use **UIWebView** programmatically in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "add in" images to a UITextView.   You can place UITextViews (either scrolling or non-scrolling, non-scrolling it sounds like in your case) and UIImages inside a UIScrollView and they will all scroll together, that's probably the easiest way of doing what you want to do.

In code:

```
UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:MyScrollViewFrame];
UITextView *textView = [.. create your text view ... ];
UIImageView *imageView = [... create your image view ... ];
[sv addSubview:textView];
[sv addSubview:imageView];
```

In interface builder:

[image]